# Order list in nested level using xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the xml with many lists in sequential order. But I need to convert all the list sequence into nested level basis. Below I mentioned the input and expected output. Please any one try.

Input

```
<body>
    <p>
        <list level="1" type="normal">
            <li id="(1)"> A </li>
            <li id="(2)"> B </li>
        </list>
        <list level="2">
            <li id="(a)">is</li>
            <li id="(b)">was</li>
            <li id="(c)">other market</li>
        </list>
        <list level="3">
            <li id="(1)">first</li>
            <li id="(2)">second</li>
            <li id="(3)">third</li>
        </list>
    </p>
    <sec>
        <list level="1" type="normal">
            <li id="(1)"> A </li>
        </list>
        <list level="2">
            <li id="(a)">is</li>
            <li id="(b)">was</li>
            <li id="(c)">other market</li>
        </list>
    </sec>
</body>
```

Expected ouput is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <p>
        <list level="1" type="normal">
            <li id="(1)"> A </li>
            <li id="(2)"> B <list level="2">
                    <li id="(a)">is</li>
                    <li id="(b)">was</li>
                    <li id="(c)">other market <list level="3">
                            <li id="(1)">first</li>
                            <li id="(2)">second</li>
                            <li id="(3)">third</li>
                        </list>
                    </li>
                </list>
            </li>
        </list>
    </p>
    <sec>
        <list level="1" type="normal">
            <li id="(1)"> A <list level="2">
                    <li id="(a)">is</li>
                    <li id="(b)">was</li>
                    <li id="(c)">other market</li>
                </list>
            </li>
        </list>
    </sec>
</body>
```

Anyone please help me

I have added one more input in detail. The main logic is to group list according to value of level attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <p>
        <list level="1" type="normal">
            <li id="(1)"> A </li>
            <li id="(2)"> B </li>
        </list>
        <list level="2">
            <li id="(a)">is</li>
            <li id="(b)">was</li>
        </list>
        <list level="3">
            <li id="(1)">first</li>
            <li id="(2)">second</li>
        </list>
        <list level="2">
            <li id="(c)">ff</li>
            <li id="(d)">sss</li>
        </list>
        <list level="1">
            <li id="(3)">C</li>
            <li id="(4)">D</li>
        </list>
    </p>
    <sec>
        <list level="1" type="normal">
            <li id="(1)"> A </li>
        </list>
        <list level="2">
            <li id="(a)">is</li>
            <li id="(b)">was</li>
            <li id="(c)">other market</li>
        </list>
    </sec>
</body>
```

The expected output is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <p>
        <list level="1" type="normal">
            <li id="(1)"> A </li>
            <li id="(2)"> B <list level="2">
                    <li id="(a)">is</li>
                    <li id="(b)">was<list level="3">
                            <li id="(1)">first</li>
                            <li id="(2)">second</li></list></li>
                    <li id="(c)">ff</li>
                    <li id="(d)">sss</li>
                </list></li>
            <li id="(3)">C</li>
            <li id="(4)">D</li>
        </list>
    </p>
    <sec>
        <list level="1" type="normal">
            <li id="(1)"> A <list level="2">
                    <li id="(a)">is</li>
                    <li id="(b)">was</li>
                    <li id="(c)">other market</li>
                </list></li>
        </list>
    </sec>
</body>
```

Comment: So what are the rules for nesting, is the `list level="2"` simply inserted as a child of the last `li` child of `list level="1"`?

Comment: We are not a coding service.  We will answer questions about specific problems you encounter while trying to implement this, but no, we will not "try" the whole problem for you.

Comment: I have tried but I cant able to bring the expected output. Here list of level 2 must comes inside the last li element of level 1 and the list of level 3 comes under last li of level 2.

Answer (score 1):

First start off with the identity template...

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This, at least, takes you half-way there!

One of the transformations you need to make is that the `p` and `sec` elements should only have one child; the `list` element of level1, so this can be achieved with another template

```
<xsl:template match="*[list]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="list[@level='1']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, you just need a template to match the last `li` in a `list`, where you copy it, and amend the following `list` as a child.

```
<xsl:template match="li[not(following-sibling::*)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../following-sibling::list[1]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Put this altogether gives this..

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="*[list]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="list[@level='1']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li[not(following-sibling::*)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../following-sibling::list[1]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This does make the assumption you do not have multiple lists with the same `levelid` under each item.

EDIT: In the case you do have multiple list items with the same `levelid` it becomes a bit more complicated, but try this XSLT instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="list" match="list" use="concat(generate-id(..), generate-id(preceding-sibling::list[@level = current()/@level - 1][1]))" />

    <xsl:template match="*[list]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="list[@level='1'][1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li[not(following-sibling::*)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('list', concat(generate-id(../..), generate-id(..)))[1]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="list">
        <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
             <xsl:apply-templates select="key('list', concat(generate-id(..), generate-id(preceding-sibling::list[@level = current()/@level - 1][1])))/li" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The requirement "you just need a template to match the last li in a list" can be directly expressed in the match pattern as `match="li[last()]"`.

Comment: Thanks for Tim and Martin. I want to tell more regarding this. Here i need to group list by value of level attribute. Here given more such input and expected output.

Comment: I have added an alternate solution to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your effort. Still I found here some problem arise if there is separate list after some paras means the list is joined with the previous list.